# jQueryUI Autocomplete Returning AJAX Error 0 when user hits enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a search box which is using the jqueryUI `.autocomplete` to get data via AJAX to give suggestions. The problem is that when a user hits enter before the autocomplete AJAX call to the source is done an error pops up in an alert box. "AJAX Error 0"

I assume when the user hits "Enter" when in the search box the browser is automatically stopping the AJAX call which resulting in a bad AJAX response which is triggering jqueryui to pop an error. Is there anyway to make this not happen? Here is some of the sample code of the autocomplete:

```
    $("#searchBar_searchAll").on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('<?php echo CController::createUrl("inventory/searchAutocomplete"); ?>', {
                searchString: extractLast(request.term),
                searchScopeRecord: $("#searchScope_recordScope option:selected").val(),
                searchScopeActive: $("#searchScope_activeScope option:selected").val(),
                searchOptions: $("#searchBar_searchoption_searchAll option:selected").val()
            }, response);
        },
        search: function() {
            var searchString = extractLast(this.value);
            if (searchString.length < 3)
                return false;
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href = '<?php echo CController::createUrl("inventory/update"); ?>' + '&id=' + ui.item.value;

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Edit: The problem only happens sometimes upon further testing and it seems to happen almost every time on a slower machine. It seems related to how fast the machine executes the Javascript.

It seems that the AJAX error 0 occurs because when the user submits the search it cancels the AJAX request. It seems like when this is cancelled jquery-ui's .autocomplete is likely triggering an error pop-up due to getting no data. Is there anyway I could cleanly cancel the AJAX request then when someone hits enter or the submit button so that such an AJAX error does not occur?

Comment: Please precise which jQuery and jQuery UI versions, which browser, and if the `input` is inside a `form` or not. I can't reproduce your issue under Chrome, latest version of jQuery

Comment: @Twistingnether `jQuery v1.11.2` and `jQuery UI - v1.11.4`. The input field is within a form and the form is within a table.

Comment: Ok @ComputerLocus, and which browser? Also are you talking about a native `alert()` showing the error or some jQuery popup? I don't see any `alert()` in jQuery's code

Comment: @Twistingnether it is an alert box. It is from jquery-ui. It is happening on all browsers however Chrome suppresses the alert and indicates this in the console. In the console Chrome indicates it "blocked" an alert during navigation.

Comment: As this is getting data from your Web Server via PHP, can you describe the number of results that are returned from a single character. Since you're executing the search right away, for example, if the User enters `"a"`, are you expecting 5 results or 5000?

Comment: Also, where is the `<form>` elements and are there any callbacks ior bindings for this form? You can check to see what the status is of the AJAX call in the `.submit()` callback for the form and then manually cancel the AJAX request if the status is not desired.

Comment: Your `select` function also does not make sense. You've written it so that the User can make multiple selections, yet if they make a selection it redirects the page to a new URL. Please clarify what you want to happen and please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i think  you can do this with blocking enter key via keycode on change event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you are looking for enter search functionality.

you just need this property

```
$("#searchBar_searchAll").autocomplete({ autoFocus: true });
```

I didn't have your php api code so i put a sample array source for my autocomplete.

here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/u5m0wdg2/3/)

another example with ajax source. but its already mentioned atleast we need to wait while ajax request should complete and return with results.

here is another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/u5m0wdg2/10/) with ajax source.

Answer (score 0):

The browser submits the form by default if you hit enter. While the ajax-request needs time (if not delivered from browser-cache), the browser-form-submit fires immediately and breaks your running ajax-request. As result you see those ajax error.

Maybe you can set a helper-variable if you press Enter and skip the JSON-function, if this var is true.

```
var bEnterPressed = false;

$("#searchBar_searchAll").on("keydown", function(event) {
    var iKey = event.keyCode || event.which; // event.which is for old IE compatibility

    bEnterPressed = false;

    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Detect Enter = key 37
    if( iKey === 37 ) {
        bEnterPressed = true;
    }

}).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        if( bEnterPressed ) { return false; } // skip ajax-request, if Enter was pressed

        try {
            $.getJSON('<?php echo CController::createUrl("inventory/searchAutocomplete"); ?>', {
                searchString: extractLast(request.term),
                searchScopeRecord: $("#searchScope_recordScope option:selected").val(),
                searchScopeActive: $("#searchScope_activeScope option:selected").val(),
                searchOptions: $("#searchBar_searchoption_searchAll option:selected").val()
            }, response);
        } catch(e) {
            // ignore ajax-errors
        }

    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: The problem is that this is for autocomplete. So what happens is someone starts typing and rather than waiting for the autocomplete result to return in a dropdown they hit enter to go straight to a separate search results page. I basically want the field to work like a Google Search page. When you type there are suggestions, but you can hit enter at anytime to just search and ignore those auto completes. The problem here is that when someone hits enter it's throwing this alert for the ajax error. It doesn't make sense why the jquery-ui library would throw the error in an alert like that.

Comment: I can imagine that jQuery UI has a try-catch-block which shows the error-popup. If you catch this error before jQuery UI does, would it help? The Ajax-Request is done by the $.getJSON()-function. You can try to put a "try{...} catch(e) {}" around it... See code above.